# Is there any official Eberron material about the death dragonmark?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic, eberron

I play a lot in Eberron settings. I was planning to make a campaign where an NPC has the death dragonmark, but I couldn't find any official sources for that.

Am I just bad at searching, or it is just that there is nothing?

Comment: I could swear I saw this exact question just recently, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Explicitly left undefined

It is one of the official “mysteries” of Eberron, up there with the draconic prophecy as a whole, whether or not warforged have souls, and so on. Eberron’s authors have intentionally left it as an unknown, a blank that a DM can fill in as they see fit.

It is known that House Vol practiced necromancy, and suspected that their Mark of Death aided in that, but details are nonexistent. It has been suggested that the
pattern of dragonmarks is that they are “creative” not “destructive,” so creating undead is a far more likely function for the Mark of Death than any kind of killing function. It is also believed that Minara d’Vol used her dragonmark as part of the process that turned her half-green-dragon daughter, Erandis d’Vol, into a lich, but whether that was specifically one of the functions of the mark, or if this was a more elaborate ritual in which the Mark of Death only played a part, is unknown. It is *also* believed that Erandis d’Vol’s dragonmark, if she had ever used it in life, would have had unusual powers due to her half-dragon status. Erandis d’Vol still bears the mark upon her flesh, but it is as dead as she is.